# Low quality images when using 3g dongle

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, 3g, dongle

From time to time i use a 3g Dongle to connect to the internet, the dongle in question is a **Huawei e3131** what ive noticed is that the images it serves are compressed to a really low quality, (i can tell because when i visit the same website on wifi they are much crisper) this is obviously done to save band width, but im on a  unlimited plan and have about 5mb download so its not needed.

Any idea how i can stop this happening ?

Comment: It's possible your mobile provider is compressing the images as they travel through their servers.

Comment: Try use tor network to connect to VPN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MichaelFrank is right, a lot of providers use image compression for mobile networks and in addition have configured it badly.

Here is a citation from my answer over at StackOverflow on: [Avoiding image compression on some 3G networks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577244/2010467)

> Setting a `no-cache` header has stopped working on some providers like
>   Vodafone Germany a few years ago.
>
> Instead these providers offer a webinterface where you can adjust the
>   settings yourself. For Vodafone Germany just go to
>   [performance.vodafone.de](http://performance.vodafone.de/) and you will be greeted with the basic
>   settings dialogue, but you can also choose the option "expert
>   settings" for a more fine grained control and advanced options.
>
> [image: Basic settings]
>
> [image: Advanced settings]
>
> Links for different providers and countries or whole lists are very
>   much welcome!